# Splitting string based on some specfic conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I wanted to split the word which has , ; / but not in all places. If these characters are present before numbers or any mathematical measurements like (m, cm, %, etc), it should be retained as it is.

But if they are present after these measurements or numbers then string should be split.

**Original_Input**

Conformis
Discovery IQ
Discovery Ml
Discovery Ml DR
Discovery PET/CT 610
Discovery PET/CT 610
Maquet
Optima PET/CT 560, 560FX
Optima PET/CT 560, 560FX
Optima PET/CT 560, 560FX
Prestige II, Prestige SI, Prestige VH
Prestige II, Prestige SI, Prestige VH

**Expected output:**

**Product_input**                                    **Product_Name(output)**

Conformis                                            Conformis
Discovery IQ                                         Discovery IQ
Discovery Ml                                         Discovery Ml
Discovery Ml DR                                      Discovery Ml DR
Discovery PET/CT 610                                 CT 610
Discovery PET/CT 610                                 Discovery PET
Maquet                                               Maquet
Optima PET/CT 560, 560FX                             560FX
Optima PET/CT 560, 560FX                             CT 560
Optima PET/CT 560, 560FX                             Optima PET
Prestige II, Prestige SI, Prestige VH                Prestige VH
Prestige II, Prestige SI, Prestige VH                Prestige II, Prestige SI

, ; / after colours and measures and numbers has to be split. There are two tables where the input has to be compared and split.I have given those tables below.

I want this to be done in python. I tried using regex but am not sure how to compare with other tables and split. Also am confused of how to use regex in this or any other method if possible.

I tried using **rsplit**. But am not sure whether that is the right one. I have given the **colours and measures** table and **names** split table

**Note**

**Colors and measures table**

```
Ver
Version
Clear
disposable
non disposable
non-disposable
nondisposable
urinary
Tinted
non-colored
Small
Medium
Large
Blue
Green
white
Straight
Long
Degrees
Reference lab pack
REFILLS KITS
WITH EYE TRACKER
v2
v3
Battery
Extra Large
USP
IP
XL
Filter
FITC
Humidifier
Kit
Mask
Orange
Red
Violet
Yellow
Channels
Li-Ion
PUMP
Abutments
Monitor
Aids
step
needles
ENHANCED
Right
Left
Bridges
```

**Names table**

```
NonSplit    ID
”   193
He  2
Li  3
Be  4
Ne  10
Na  11
Mg  12
Al  13
Si  14
Cl  17
Ar  18
Ca  20
Sc  21
Ti  22
Cr  24
Mn  25
Fe  26
Co  27
Ni  28
Cu  29
Zn  30
Ga  31
Ge  32
As  33
Se  34
Br  35
Kr  36
Rb  37
Sr  38
Zr  40
Nb  41
Mo  42
Tc  43
Ru  44
Rh  45
Pd  46
Ag  47
Cd  48
Sn  50
Sb  51
Te  52
Xe  54
Cs  55
Ba  56
La  57
Ce  58
Pr  59
Nd  60
Sm  62
Eu  63
Gd  64
Tb  65
Dy  66
Ho  67
Er  68
Tm  69
Yb  70
Lu  71
Hf  72
Ta  73
Re  75
Os  76
Ir  77
Pt  78
Au  79
Hg  80
Tl  81
Pb  82
Bi  83
Po  84
At  85
Rn  86
Fr  87
Ra  88
Ac  89
Th  90
Pa  91
Np  93
Pu  94
Am  95
Bk  97
Cf  98
Es  99
Md  101
No  102
Lr  103
Rf  104
Db  105
Sg  106
Bh  107
Hs  108
Mt  109
Ds  110
Rg  111
Cn  112
Nh  113
Fl  114
Mc  115
Lv  116
Ts  117
Og  118
°   122
km  123
hm  124
dam 125
dm  127
cm  128
mm  129
µm  130
nm  131
pm  132
fm  133
in  134
ft  135
"   136
yd  137
'   138
kg  139
hg  140
dag 141
dg  143
cg  144
mg  145
µg  146
ng  147
pg  148
fg  149
lb  150
oz  151
kl  152
hl  153
dal 154
dL  156
cL  157
mL  158
µL  159
nL  160
pL  161
fL  162
fl oz   163
cc  164
℞   166
Rx  167
mol 168
ppm 169
%   170
Ω   172
Ahr 173
kWh 174
Wh  175
Ah  176
dB  178
Hz  180
λ   184
cd  185
Lm  189
AC  190
DC  191
pk  192
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: i suggest you make ur question clearer and sample size smaller. show lines that have the different delimiters, show how you want your output to look like ( in a list, tuple?) what is the relevance of the colors and measures table and the names table? kindly reword your problem statement and make it much clearer.

Comment: Please format your question，looks too messy.

Comment: I have edited the sample input and output. Colors and measures and names tables are conditions where delimiters have to be checked. If the delimiters ,;/ are before the colors and measure and names given then that should not be split, if it after them then it should be split. Output shows the split string.